# Como passar variável php como parâmetro numa chamada de função JS

Tags: php, javascript

Olá, quero passar uma variável de php, como parâmetro numa chamada de função JavaScript. Desse modo:

```
<a href="calcular($numero)">Calcular</a>
```

Já tentei fazer assim:

```
<a href="calcular(<?php echo $numero; ?>)></a>
```

Porém, o detalhe que dificulta, é que esse `<a></a>` está já dentro de um `<?php  ?>` por estar num while.

Alguma ideia de resolução?

Comment: Podes simplesmente usar concatenação, sem usar o `<?php`. Algo assim: `<a href="calcular('.$numero.')></a>`, mas depende um pouco de como estás a usar as aspas. Podes colocar o código desse `while`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Podes simplesmente usar concatenação, sem usar o `<?php`. Algo assim: `<a href="calcular('.$numero.')></a>`, mas depende um pouco de como estás a usar as aspas.

Por exemplo:

```
<?php

while ($numero< 10){
    echo '<a href="calcular('.$numero.')"></a>';
}

?>
```